# CalledProcessError: Command '\['git', 'submodule--helper', 'list'\]

Tags: yocto

all.

After I use `devtool-modify` to edit my recipe, when I bitbake my image, something wrong happend.

```
ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable do_compile\[file-checksums\], expression was ${@srctree_hash_files(d)} which triggered exception
CalledProcessError: Command '\['git', 'submodule--helper', 'list'\]' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

The variable dependency chain for the failure is: `do_compile\[file-checksums\]`

11111111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: The question is not clear, can you include the recipe content ?

Comment: I have also same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM It is not related to recipe file or bbappend file. If you don't have any bbappend file, then bitbake (or devtool build) compiles a recipe. When you have a bbappend file, then it raises this ExpansionError

Comment: Okay can you add the `bbappend` file ? Also, can you check the output of `bitbake -e <recipe> | grep ^SRC_URI=`

Comment: I found it. Under the file `/sources/poky/meta/classes/externalsrc.bbclass` there is change from `['git', 'submodule', 'list']` to `['git', 'submodule--helper', 'list']`

Comment: Can you show me the content of SRC_URI ? try with the command I mentionned

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM, Why? The problem is obvious, it is nothing to do with SRC_URI. It is related to mismatch between poky version and git version. 
It is better to remove newer git version and install 2.17.1

Answer (score 2):

Git is no longer supports submodule--helper list , so fixed in https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/commit/?id=0533edac277080e1bd130c14df0cbac61ba01a0c .
So you can either apply this commit or upgrade poky!